# Time Series Regression with Washout Period

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

A classical time series regression model with an $\text{AR}(1)$ error has the following structure

\begin{align*}
\mu_t &= \boldsymbol x^T_t \boldsymbol \beta \\
y_t &= \mu_t + e_t \\
e_t &= \theta e_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t\\
\varepsilon_t &\sim \; \text{i.i.d.} \; N(0, \sigma^2) \qquad \text{for} \; t \in \{1, \dots, n\}
\end{align*}

The average response $\mu_t$ reacts immediately on changes in the predictors $\boldsymbol x_t$. This is not realistic for my data set. Instead the average response should slowly approximate the new level $\boldsymbol x^T_t \boldsymbol \beta$ (maybe based on an exponential function). This would correspond to the following model

$$
\mu_t = (\mu_{t-1} - \boldsymbol x^T_t \boldsymbol \beta) e^{-\lambda} + \boldsymbol x^T_t \boldsymbol\beta
$$

The following simulation illustrates the new model

```
## parameters
beta <- c(10,-5)
lambda <- 0.05
theta <- 0.9
sigma <- 0.6

## design matrix
n <- 1000
x1 <- rep(0,n)
x1[c(101:200, 221:521, 600:660, 700:730)] <- 1
X <- model.matrix(~x1)

## simulate observations
mu <- vector("numeric", n)
mu[1] <- 8
for(t in 2:n){
  mu[t] <- (mu[t-1] - as.vector(X[t,] %*% beta))*exp(-lambda) + as.vector(X[t,] %*% beta)
}
set.seed(1)
y <- mu + arima.sim(model = list(ar = c(theta)), n = n, sd = 0.6)
```

[image]

**My question**

How can I estimate the parameters $\boldsymbol\beta$, $\lambda$ and $\theta$ and do inference (testing, confidence intervals) for such a model?

Comment: hi: you might want to consider what is referred to as the koyck distributed lag if you have one predictor. If you have more than one predictor, then an autoregressive distributed lag model. These are models where the effects of the predictor(s) are spread out over time rather than right away so kind of similar to what you explained. Any decent econometrics text should discuss them. A deeper and more detailed discussion is contained in Andrew Harvey's text "econometric analysis of time series".

Comment: @mlofton Thanks for your suggestion. I guess a **distributed lag model** would have the form: $y_t = \beta_1 x_{t} + \beta_2 x_{t-1} + \dots + \varepsilon_t$. Now, that could imply a lot of parameters if the decay ($\lambda$) is relatively small. Is there a way to have less parameters? I my model above all the influence of previous average responses is determined by a single parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: What you wrote is not a distributed lag because there's no lagged dependent variable. I suggest reading about the koyck DL first ( one predictor ) because that will give you a feel for why you need the lagged dependent variable. I have too many papers on koyck DL and wouldn't know what to send you but any decent econometrics text will discuss it. Off the top of head, Baltagi's orange book is short but sweet. Harvey's text is the best for it. If you're going to  be into this stuff for a while, it's worth the investment. The book is unique and not a standard econometrics textbook.

Comment: Also, if you can't find anything useful, ( the textbooks besides harvey are just so-so on this stuff ), I'll send you some koyck dl papers from the political science field that are  the best out there for a good intro. I'd just have to find them but it won't be that hard. I'm just in a rush at the moment. So, let me know.